# How to get the characters surround specific pattern in one capturing group?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
any123thing
```

Here is my specific pattern:

```
\d+ // which matches '123' in the string above
```

Now I want to get `anything` in the one capturing group. Is it possible?

---

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
(\w+(?:\d+)\w+)
```

But `$1` in this ^ regex is  `any123thing`. While I want to get this: `anything`.

**Note:** I don't want to use `replace` function.

Comment: [No](https://google.com)

Comment: You can use [`([a-zA-Z]+)\d*([a-zA-Z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oJ4hM5/2) and use captured groups `$1$2`.

Comment: @Tushar Yes I knew it .. I wanted to know how can I do that using *one* capturing group. anyway ok thank you

Comment: I voted to close the question as the answer provided by @Tushar seems complete to me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You cannot

According to [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) *(emphasis mine)*:

> Besides grouping part of a regular expression together, parentheses also create a numbered capturing group. It stores the part of the string matched by the part of the regular expression ***inside*** the parentheses.

Consider you example:

[`(\w+(?:\d+)\w+)`](https://regexper.com/#(%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B)%5Cw%2B))

[image]

Everything "inside the parentheses" is captured, including the non-capturing group.

In this case, it is effectively equivalent to using just the outer capturing group:

[`(\w+\d+\w+)`](https://regexper.com/#(%5Cw%2B%5Cd%2B%5Cw%2B))

Whether you have a capturing group, non-capturing group, or no group at all inside of another group. The parent group will capture everything "inside the parentheses".

Non-capturing groups are a tool for optimization when you don't have the need to use a back reference. But don't let the name fool you: if they are inside of another group, *that* group still captures the match. In other words, they do not exclude themselves from parent groups.

[@Tushar](/questions/35893218/how-to-get-the-characters-surround-specific-pattern-in-one-capturing-group#comment59447285_35893218) had suggested using [`([a-zA-Z]+)\d*([a-zA-Z]+)`](https://regexper.com/#(%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B)%5Cd*(%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B)) and using the `$1$2` captured group back references in tandem. This is the only approach if you're using regular expressions.